# How to select polyline blocks spatially nearest to clicked point in Google Earth Engine?

Tags: google-earth-engine

I have multiple polyline blocks, and all of them are in one feature collection, i can not separate or filter blocks from this feature collection.

My aim is, when i clicked on the map, i want to select connected polylines near of clicked point with spatial join or another way.

For example, in below picture, when i clicked in red circle area, i want to select all the polylines above, in the green circle, not all polylines in feature collection

How can achieve this?

[image]

[The code is there](https://code.earthengine.google.com/4371b974ae54a2e0f45fecee1c3a30a6)

```
var geometry = ee.Geometry.MultiLineString(
            [[[-84.3780015640443, 33.75441463961663],
              [-84.37660681535655, 33.7544057193743],
              [-84.37557684709483, 33.754378958641716],
              [-84.37435375978404, 33.75437003839567],
              [-84.37218653490001, 33.75432543715156],
              [-84.37214361955577, 33.75544938142884],
              [-84.37111365129405, 33.75544938142884],
              [-84.37010514070445, 33.7554672216954],
              [-84.36896788408214, 33.75584186643547],
              [-84.3679701023286, 33.75585078652839]],
             [[-84.37556611825877, 33.75437003839567],
              [-84.3755339317506, 33.75281790145396],
              [-84.37470781137401, 33.75046288140196]],
             [[-84.37438594629222, 33.75437003839567],
              [-84.37438594629222, 33.75339772601306],
              [-84.3743108444398, 33.75281790145396],
              [-84.37354909707958, 33.75068589743704]],
             [[-84.37217580606395, 33.754334357402236],
              [-84.37206851770335, 33.7537991407185],
              [-84.37111365129405, 33.751658240572404],
              [-84.37103854944164, 33.75148875036065]],
             [[-84.37219726373607, 33.754334357402236],
              [-84.3688176803773, 33.754262995370766],
              [-84.36884986688548, 33.75329960213254],
              [-84.36749803354198, 33.753692096980814],
              [-84.36753022005016, 33.752577050099816],
              [-84.36617838670665, 33.752951707469485],
              [-84.36387168695384, 33.75352261078947]],
             [[-84.37107844918253, 33.755440685270145],
              [-84.3710355338383, 33.757643930330495],
              [-84.36998410790446, 33.757643930330495],
              [-84.36994119256022, 33.759285177297436],
              [-84.36781688302042, 33.759285177297436],
              [-84.36786013550798, 33.760908201402486]],
             [[-84.3688748999043, 33.754264341273775],
              [-84.36642872528272, 33.754264341273775],
              [-84.36400400833325, 33.754585469942505],
              [-84.36299549774365, 33.754853076247635],
              [-84.36325298980908, 33.75606621435438],
              [-84.3632744474812, 33.756654936954604],
              [-84.36218010620313, 33.75663709693521],
              [-84.3622659368916, 33.75740421441674]],
             [[-84.38083310209188, 33.75442267098988],
              [-84.38239951215658, 33.7544405114701],
              [-84.38636918149862, 33.75055119897731],
              [-84.38731331907186, 33.74939150743928]],
             [[-84.38430924497519, 33.75709870153405],
              [-84.38222785077963, 33.75709870153405],
              [-84.3823136814681, 33.75447619241936]],
             [[-84.38222785077963, 33.7544583519466],
              [-84.38651938520346, 33.754511873353785],
              [-84.38615460477743, 33.754940043408624],
              [-84.38609023176107, 33.7555822944814],
              [-84.38761372648153, 33.755635815186956],
              [-84.38849349103842, 33.756224540742835],
              [-84.38911576352987, 33.75683110223852]],
             [[-84.38437361799154, 33.754511873353785],
              [-84.38688416562948, 33.752032013063996],
              [-84.38761372648153, 33.75115780061114],
              [-84.38845057569418, 33.75005164146845]],
             [[-84.3884720333663, 33.75005164146845],
              [-84.39012427411947, 33.750890182772274],
              [-84.39207692228231, 33.752032013063996],
              [-84.39347167097006, 33.75278133092943],
              [-84.39478058896933, 33.75354848291214]],
             [[-84.38995261274252, 33.75078313540286],
              [-84.38898701749716, 33.75187144409801],
              [-84.39021010480795, 33.7525137181578],
              [-84.39130444608602, 33.75320950962664]],
             [[-84.3779363163558, 33.76161208378611],
              [-84.37789340101156, 33.76418085925865],
              [-84.37780757032309, 33.767498746960406],
              [-84.38209910474691, 33.76757009797314],
              [-84.38184161268148, 33.771351616631094]],
             [[-84.3779363163558, 33.76410950542403],
              [-84.37360186658773, 33.76400247456068],
              [-84.37338728986654, 33.76632144667305],
              [-84.37274355970297, 33.77128026876716],
              [-84.37282939039144, 33.77302827432979]],
             [[-84.37338728986654, 33.76635712267698],
              [-84.37192816816244, 33.766392798666025],
              [-84.37171359144125, 33.77124459481293],
              [-84.36776537977133, 33.77110189884741],
              [-84.36772246442709, 33.773385005777094]]]);
    
    var trainingData = ee.FeatureCollection(geometry)
    
    Map.addLayer(trainingData)
    
    var SEARCH_LAYER = null
    
    Map.onClick(function(coords){
    
    var searchpoint = ee.Geometry.Point(coords.lon, coords.lat);
     
    var spatialFilter = ee.Filter.withinDistance({
      distance: 100,
      leftField: '.geo',
      rightField: '.geo',
      maxError: 10
    })
    
    // Join the points to themselves.
    var joined = ee.Join.saveAll({
      matchesKey: 'neighbors', 
      measureKey: 'distance',
      ordering: 'distance'
    }).apply({
      primary: searchpoint, 
      secondary: trainingData, 
      condition: spatialFilter
    });
    
    var withNearestDist = joined.map(function(f) {
      var nearestFeat = ee.Feature(ee.List(f.get('neighbors')).get(0));
      return nearestFeat
    });
    
    print(withNearestDist)
    
    var selectedFeature = withNearestDist
        .map(function(feature) {
          return feature.select(['label', 'text','distance'], null, false);
        })
        .first();
    
    selectedFeature.evaluate(function(evaluatedFeature) {
          if (evaluatedFeature) {
            var properties = evaluatedFeature.properties;
            print('PROPERTIESSSSS ', properties)
            SEARCH_LAYER = ui.Map.Layer(ee.Feature(withNearestDist.first()), {color: 'red'}, 'Search Result');
            Map.add(SEARCH_LAYER);
            print('Closest feature found: ', withNearestDist);
            print(properties.distance)
            print(properties.label);
    
          } else {
          }
        });
    });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your lines are all in a single MultiLineString, so they are always going to be treated like a single geometry.  In order to work with them separately, you need to split that geometry into multiple geometries.  If you already know where the groups are, then just manually make 3 MultiLines.  Otherwise, you could do something like this to find them automatically.

```
// Split MultiLine into one feature per line.
var lines = ee.FeatureCollection(geometry.geometries().map(function(g) {
  return ee.Feature(ee.Geometry(g))
}))

// Compute distance from each line and make outline polygons that are <= 10m.
var outlines = lines.distance().lt(10).selfMask()
  .reduceToVectors({
    reducer: ee.Reducer.countEvery(), 
    geometry: lines.geometry().bounds(), 
    scale: 1
  })

// Collect all the lines within each outline into one feature per group.
var groups = outlines.map(function(outline) {
  return ee.Feature(lines.filterBounds(outline.geometry()).geometry())
})

print(groups)
Map.addLayer(groups)
```

https://code.earthengine.google.com/4c09a48aecee85653488a5ddc7016f2f

Comment: Dear Gorelick, thank you very much, i am gratefull to you. Could you explain blocks for me and other users above code blocks?

Comment: They're commented; which part needs more explanation?

Comment: ok, i noticed comments, thank you. I tested this code with featurecollection, it was very slow. What is your recommendation? https://code.earthengine.google.com/69268d0a895741d7b4d85525c81a5cdc Is it possible and do you recommend a loop, map or itetate algorithm with spatial join?

Comment: Re-export the grouped polylines as their own table; then things will be fast.

Comment: And please, can you take a look this question: https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/414056/how-to-combine-feature-collections-statistics-for-grouped-reductions-in-google-e